# Agile Central example cumulative flow diagram not rendering

Tags: rally

After checking out the source from: https://github.com/RallyApps/app-catalog

I attempted to build the Portfolio Item cumulative flow diagram `src/apps/charts/rpm/cfd` locally using
`rally-app-builder build` which shows no errors

Launching App-debug.html allows me to input the relevant settings, but once I click 'save', nothing renders and there are no errors logged to the JS console either, making debugging challenging.

I attempted to copy the build output into a custom html app inside rally, which displayed the same behaviour.

Is this a bug with the example app? Or have I missed some crucial configuration step?

EDIT:
Extra info - I tried running via the rally-app-builder to no avail (think it's related to this issue: https://github.com/RallyApps/rally-app-builder/issues/45). I attempted to flatten the structure and the result of that was a cross-origin request error.

Running from file resulted in a 403 for the SDK

Answer (score 0):

Sorry about that- that Rally App Builder issue is definitely the problem you're running into.  Just as a test I downloaded the built html output for that app from the app catalog release: https://github.com/RallyApps/app-catalog/releases/download/2.1/2.1.zip

It worked when installed on a custom html app on my dashboard once I edited the app settings and configured a portfolio item.

If you're looking to tweak this app from source you'll probably have to copy all those files referenced in config.json that live in parent directories into the main app directory and fix the paths in config.json.  Then you should be able to build and run the app normally using Rally App Builder.

It seems this app was really not designed to be run externally, so I added a little code to ease the issues I ran into:

In PortfolioChartAppBase.js, _loadSavedPortfolioItem function:

```
scope: this,
fetch: ['Name', 'ObjectID'] //this is new
```

And I added some default settings as a top level config object in CumulativeFlowChartApp.js (since the code to force into settings mode doesn't seem to work correctly when running externally):

```
  config: {
        defaultSettings: {
            portfolioItemPicker: '/portfolioitem/feature/52725935318', //insert a valid oid here
            startDate: 'actualstartdate',
            endDate: 'actualenddate',
            chartAggregationType: 'storycount'
        }
    },
```

Comment: Thanks for responding - I'm trying to modify the app.

Comment: Thanks for responding - I'm trying to modify the app.

Flattening the structure and building/running using the builder results in an error:

XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/v2.0/user:current/permissions/all. The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header has a value 'http://localhost:63342' that is not equal to the supplied origin. Origin 'http://localhost:1337' is therefore not allowed access.
`

I also attempted running off port 63442, but that had a similar error.

Comment: Are you using chrome?  We run into this bug periodically.  Usually running in an incognito window and/or clearing all cache and making sure the developer tools are open tend to resolve that cors error...

Comment: Yep, I'm using chrome. Cleared the cache and the CORS errors are gone, thanks for that! The content is _still_ not rendering after inputting the settings however. Have tried this in chrome + incognito and in safari with caches emptied.

Would changing the in-code refs to remove the references to directories that have been flattened in extjs definitions be necessary? E.g find all references to `somepath.settings.somefile` and change them to `somefile`? I figured that wouldn't be required, but I'm running out of things to try.

Comment: Can you give a link to your code?  A github repo perhaps?  Are you getting any console errors?

Comment: Have pushed my code up here:
https://github.com/labrooks/app-catalog/tree/flatten_pi_cfd_dependencies

It's just moving paths + fixing the config.

I'm getting 0 console errors.

Comment: I just updated my answer above to work around the limitations of this app running externally.  Sorry for the trouble.  Hopefully that gets you unstuck!

Comment: I downloaded the file and put the uncompressed file into rally as Custom HTML.

Everything but the statsbanner showsup, am I missing something?

I do see the checkbox which says show the Iteration Progress Banner.